# NoSuchElementException - Java and selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

Implicit wait program codes in Java Selenium are correct, but there is some error in the console. This problem is with config of java and selenium.

Error:

```
Nov 29, 2023 10:49:09 PM org.openqa.selenium.manager.SeleniumManager lambda$runCommand$1
INFO: Driver path: C:\\Users\\IT.cache\\selenium\\chromedriver\\win64\\119.0.6045.105\\chromedriver.exe
Nov 29, 2023 10:49:09 PM org.openqa.selenium.manager.SeleniumManager lambda$runCommand$1
INFO: Browser path: C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
Nov 29, 2023 10:49:12 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 119, so returning the closest version found: 116
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input\[@name='q'\]"}
(Session info: chrome=119.0.6045.160)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Build info: version: '4.12.0', revision: '249f2a7d1b\*'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.8.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: \[3faa765842476d2db4414b0a4db4cf02, findElement {using=xpath, value=//input\[@name='q'\]}\]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 119.0.6045.160, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 119.0.6045.105 (38c72552c5e..., userDataDir: C:\\Users\\IT\\AppData\\Local\\T...}, fedcm:accounts: true, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:59036}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: windows, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:59036/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 119.0.6045.160, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 3faa765842476d2db4414b0a4db4cf02
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:200)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:133)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:52)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:191)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:196)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:171)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:602)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ElementLocation$ElementFinder$2.findElement(ElementLocation.java:165)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ElementLocation.findElement(ElementLocation.java:59)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:359)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:353)
at selenium.ImplicitWait.main(ImplicitWait.java:24)
```

Comment: Can you edit the question and share your code.